# Laravel custom class not found?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, provider

I'm getting the following error

> "Class 'Martins\ArtisanGUI\ArtisanGUIServiceProvider' not found",

I already write it in `config/app.php` like `Martins\ArtisanGUI\ArtisanGUIServiceProvider::class` and recheck `namespaces`, and composer but I can't figure out what is wrong.

[image: Composer And Provider Code]

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` if you haven't regenerated the autoload files after changing composer.json

Comment: @Devon already did it, keeps showing the same error

Comment: Pedro, let me know if my updated answer works for you (using a local VCS repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're editing the composer file of your package, not your project. 
As the package does not appear to be installed and managed by composer, you need to make the project's composer aware of this package.

You should be able to add a local vcs repository in your project's composer.json file:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "packages/martins-74/artisangui"
    }
],
"require": {
    "martins-74/artisangui": "*"
}
```

This will make it so you won't have to duplicate any composer rules across both json files.

Answer (score 0):

you have two composer.json files in you projects :

1. the root of you Laravel project
2. in your package root (packages/martins-74/artisangui)

in the first composer.json file (the laravel composer.json):

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Martines\\ArtisanGUI\\" : "packages/martins-74/artisangui/src"            
}
```

the seconds composer.json file (your package composer.json):

```
"psr-4": {
     "Martines\\ArtisanGUI\\": "src",
}
```

after that run `composer dump-autoload`

hope this work for you